# Add to Campaign Custom button on custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community, visual-workflow

Is it possible to add a custom button "Add to Campaign" with the default salesforce functionality on custom object, as I am not able to bring that button in my reports for that custom object?

Thanks,
Sarika

Comment: you can build a custom report type between the custom object and campaign if they are related to each other

Comment: No that's not possible. I tried already.

Comment: does the custom object have a lookup relationship to Campaign?  Can the custom object be associated to many Campaigns? What is your schema?